# Swift Discrepancy of UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift4.2

```
import UIKit

class My_CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageV: UIImageView!

    let collectionArray = generateRandomData()

    var index = 0

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func getCellSize(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: 44, height: 44)
    }

    override func prepareForReuse()
    {
        self.collectionView.contentOffset = .zero
    }

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
    {
//        let frame = self.collectionView.frame
//        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
//
//        let height: CGFloat = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
//        self.collectionViewHeight.constant = height
//        self.collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.minY, width: frame.width, height: height)
//        return self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize

        self.collectionViewHeight.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        return self.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    }

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize
    {
        self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.collectionViewHeight.constant = collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
        return self.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UIView.layoutFittingCompressedSize)
    }
}

extension My_CustomTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        let number = Int(self.numberLabel.text!)! + 10
        return number
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollVCell", for: indexPath) as! My_CustomCollectionViewCell
//        let number = Int(self.numberLabel.text!)!
        cell.numberlabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }


}

extension My_CustomTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: 44, height: 44)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 8.0
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

class My_CustomViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Enable automatic row auto layout calculations
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        // Set the estimatedRowHeight to a non-0 value to enable auto layout.
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}

extension My_CustomViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 66
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TbVCell", for: indexPath) as! My_CustomTableViewCell

        cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.nameLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        cell.numberLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

        cell.index = indexPath.row

        print("cellForRowAt-----------\(indexPath.row)")
        return cell
    }


}
```

[storyboard settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCO14.png)

here I am not able to get the required number of collection cells as expected by the numberOfItemsInSection function which is increasing with the tableviewcell number like 64 collectionview items for 64rth tableviewcell.

What I need to do to get exact matching of number of items with tableviewcell.
with none of the above variables I am able to keep track of the count to match.

Regards

Comment: Random number of items are coming in UICollectionView.

Comment: Resolved for now the number just by adding the following line               cell.awakeFromNib()
cell.collectionView.reloadData()